# EF Core running migrations from asp.net code throws exception

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

I am using EF core for the first time in my asp.net WebApi application (REST services),m using the SQLite provider. I have installed the Nuget package v2.0.1.

I have added my context , models etc, and everything seems to be working. I now wanted to try using Migrations. Following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/) I have added my Migration, and all the expected files seem to have been created.

To test, I delete my SQLite database file and run the application, 
however, when I call the `Migrate method in code, I get the following exception...

[image]

The weird thing is, when I close the debugger, the file and table is actually created. The migration table is present, but has no rows.

If I start again, ie delete the database, and then just run the migration from the Package Manager Console, then all works fine, ie I see...

```
    PM> Update-Database
    Applying migration '20180301030031_InitialCreate'.
    Done.
    PM>
```

an also the database is create, and this time the Migration table has the row of data I expect..

[image]

Any one have any ideas why this doesn't work when I just run it in code?

Thanks in advance for any help

**[EDIT 1]**

I get the same problem if I add a new Migration after just added a field. The first time I run, I gt the exception. If I then run again, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I was considering just deleting this post, as the issue seemed to magically resolved itself.

I ran the same code (on the same database file) in a sample WPF application, and had no problems, so it seemed to be when running in the IIS process (and after doing iiresets to force the application to rerun the initialisation code which would then do the call to `context.Database.Migrate();`

At any rate, it now seems to work (but have no idea why it started working)